# Torque scredriver for plastic part

Tags: torque, screw

I use 3D printing to print parts made of pure polypropylene.

These parts have some holes that I tap in order to screw some plastic Luer adaptors:

https://www.coleparmer.com/i/cole-parmer-female-luer-x-1-4-28-unf-thread-pp-25-pk-45508-66/4550866

There will be liquid (organic solvents) in these polypropylene parts, and I need to make sure the Luer adaptors are properly tighten in the parts. For now I do it manually with a 8 hexagonal key, but I would like to do it properly with a torque screwdriver.

[image]

My question is:
Do torque screwdrivers work for plastic parts like the Luer adaptors above ? I assume the torque range would have to be pretty low.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not quite sure what this has to do with motor vehicle maintenance & repair? The only way to tell if it's going to work is to torque it. If you are torquing it, you should have a preset value your are torquing it to. If that's correct, you're just going to have to try it and see if it will stand up to it. If you don't have the torque value already, I doubt anyone here is going to be able to provide it for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I posted here because I think there are people here that have experience with screwing, even if my question is not related to motors. And no, I don't have any torque values since this plastic parts are home made. My question is more about the sensitivity of the tools: do you think they are senstivive enough for plastic bits ?

Comment: Sensitivity depends on the tool used. Really, the only reason to use a torque wrench is if you are trying to get it to a specific clamping force. If there is a need to get every single one of them the same, then you'd need one. If the object is to ensure whatever you are tightening down is secure, then snug it up and go for it. Really, I'm not sure on this why you'd need one in the first place. If you're worried about it sealing, use some teflon paste on the threads.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to motor vehicle maintenance and repair.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2: If I really go for it, the adaptor "jumps" in the thread I taped and kinda breaks it, then the adaptor starts leaking. I don't want to add any paste to my plastic parts, because the chemistry I'm doing inside the parts might get messed up by the paste. Do you think the wrench key would insure a proper tightening of the adaptor ?

Comment: That's just something you'll have to deal with, I'd think. If you don't want to use liquid Teflon, you could use Teflon tape. Either way, Teflon is one of the least reactive substances known to man, which means it shouldn't interfere with whatever your doing. You could also just put some kind of super glue on it which would keep it together as well as seal it up. The torque you'll most likely have to figure out by touch ... get used to how much it can take and don't give it anymore.

Comment: Perhaps it's a custom methanol filter for injecting into a high-boost turbo system.   *In any case*, the answer is "YES".  A properly adjusted torque screwdriver will do what you want - provided you have it set to the right final value, give the adapter fitting, the thread tolerance class, and the materials used.  The Luer fitting people might have some data.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you start with the material you are using get the failure limit and use, say, 50% of that value and then purchase a torque wrench that has that value roughly in the middle of its range. Of course you may need to go significantly lower than 50% as the limiting factor could be the quality of the threads formed by your 3d printing process...

There are several companies that sell torque wrenches which are capable of precision torque settings : it depends on the environment you are working in : production with 100's a day or home mechanic 3 per month...

Comment: It's for work, like 5 screws a day, but I don't want to mess it up because there is nasty stuff inside these plastic parts, and sometimes they are under pressure. I don't want them to leak. Price is not too much an object here. OK I'll start with that and keep you posted.